# Solving the following integral for Fourier Series.

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

I need to solve the Fourier coefficients of
$\mathrm{f}\left(x\right) = \sin\left(\pi x\right)$.
I know, since $\mathrm{f}$ is an $odd$ function, that the coefficients are given by:

\begin{align}
b_{n} & =
\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}\mathrm{f}\left(t\right)
\sin\left(\frac{2n\pi t}{L}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t =
\int_{0}^{2}\sin\left(\pi t\right)\sin\left(n\pi t\right)\,\mathrm{d}t =
\\[5mm] & =
-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2}\sin\left(\left(n + 1\right)\pi t\right)\,\mathrm{d}t + \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2}\sin\left(\left(n - 1\right)\pi t\right)\,\mathrm{d}t = 0
\end{align}

I however, found that it should be equal to
$b_n=-\,\frac{2}{\left(4n^{2} - 1\right)\pi}$.

My question is, what am I doing wrong ?.

Comment: What's the domain of your Fourier series? (It looks to be $[0,2]$ but you should say so.)

Comment: Who told you it should be that other value? That may be the result for a different value of $L$.

Comment: @Semiclassical I have chosen $[0,2]$, as 2 is the period of our function $f(t)$

Comment: That $\sin \pi x$ has period 2 does not imply that the Fourier series must have this period as well. Indeed, if you take $L=2$ as the period, then $f(x)=\sin \pi x$ is itself a (one-term) Fourier series. You will need to check the problem statement to get the domain of periodicity.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\mrm{f}\pars{x} \equiv \sin\pars{\pi x} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}b_{n}\sin\pars{\pi n x}
\\[5mm] \implies &\
\int_{-1}^{1}\mrm{f}\pars{x}\sin\pars{n\pi x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}
b_{m}\int_{-1}^{1}\sin\pars{\pi m x}\sin\pars{\pi n x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] \implies &\
\int_{-1}^{1}\sin\pars{\pi x}\sin\pars{n\pi x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}
b_{m}\int_{-1}^{1}\sin\pars{\pi m x}\sin\pars{\pi n x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] \implies &\
2\,\delta_{n1}\int_{0}^{1}{1 - \cos\pars{2\pi x} \over 2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}
b_{m}\bracks{%
2\,\delta_{mn}\int_{0}^{1}{1 - \cos\pars{2\pi nx} \over 2}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] \implies &\
2\delta_{n1} = 2b_{n} \implies \bbox[10px,border:1px groove navy]{b_{n} = \delta_{n1}} \\ &
\end{align}